# Kd Tree Iterative implementation ( C++ )

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, kdtree

Hello Does anybody has iterative implementation of Kd-Tree in C++.
I tried but it is failing when the number of nodes are odd.
Here is my code so far. I am referring http://ldots.org/kdtree/#buildingAkDTree site for details.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>


struct Point {
    double pt[2];
    int id;
};

typedef std::vector<Point> TPointVector;

struct KdNode {
    double point[2];
    int id;
    double desc;
    bool leaf;

    KdNode *left;
    KdNode *right;
    KdNode *parent;
    KdNode(KdNode *parent_):parent(parent_),leaf(false){}
    KdNode(KdNode *parent_,TPointVector::iterator itr, int depth, TPointVector &pv);
    KdNode(KdNode *t, TPointVector &pv);

};

KdNode::KdNode(KdNode *parent_,TPointVector::iterator itr, int depth, TPointVector &pv) {
    parent = parent_ ;
    left   = 0;
    right  = 0;
    desc   = itr->pt[depth % 2 ];
    leaf   = false;
}

KdNode::KdNode(KdNode *t, TPointVector &pv) {
    id       = pv[0].id;
    point[0] = pv[0].pt[0];
    point[1] = pv[0].pt[1];
    left     = 0;
    right    = 0;
    parent   = t;
    leaf     = true;
}

KdNode *pRoot = 0;


struct ComparePoints {
    int cord;
    ComparePoints(int  cord_) : cord(cord_ % 2) { };
    bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) const {
        return lhs.pt[cord] < rhs.pt[cord];
    }
};
void buildLeftTree(std::stack<TPointVector > &stackL) {
    KdNode *pCurrent = pRoot;
    KdNode **pNode  = &(pCurrent->left);
    int depth      = 0; 
    bool changeDirection = false;
    while (! stackL.empty()) {
        TPointVector pv = stackL.top(); 
        stackL.pop();
        if ( pv.size() != 1 ) { 
            std::sort(pv.begin(), pv.end(), ComparePoints(++depth));

            *pNode = new KdNode(pCurrent, pv.begin() + pv.size()/2, depth, pv);

            TPointVector lvp,rvp;
            std::size_t median = pv.size() / 2;
            std::copy(pv.begin(), pv.begin() + median, std::back_inserter(lvp));
            std::copy(pv.begin() + median, pv.end(), std::back_inserter(rvp));

            stackL.push(rvp); 
            stackL.push(lvp);

            if ( changeDirection ) {
                pCurrent = pCurrent->right;
                changeDirection = false;
            } else {
                pCurrent = pCurrent->left;
            }           
            pNode = &(pCurrent->left);

        } else {
            KdNode **pNodeLeft   = &(pCurrent->left);
            *pNodeLeft  = new KdNode(pCurrent, pv);
            pv = stackL.top();
            stackL.pop();

            KdNode **pNodeRight   = &(pCurrent->right);
            *pNodeRight  = new KdNode(pCurrent,pv);

            pCurrent = pCurrent->parent;
            pNode  = &(pCurrent->right);
            changeDirection = true;
            depth--;
        }           
    }
}

void buildRightTree(std::stack<TPointVector > &stackR) {
    KdNode *pCurrent = pRoot;
    KdNode **pNode  = &(pCurrent->right);
    int depth      = 0; 
    bool changeDirection = true;
    while (! stackR.empty()) {
        TPointVector pv = stackR.top(); 
        stackR.pop();

        if ( pv.size() != 1 ) { 
            std::sort(pv.begin(), pv.end(), ComparePoints(++depth));
            *pNode = new KdNode(pCurrent, pv.begin() + pv.size()/2, depth, pv);

            TPointVector lvp,rvp;
            std::size_t median = pv.size() / 2;
            std::copy(pv.begin(), pv.begin() + median, std::back_inserter(lvp));
            std::copy(pv.begin() + median, pv.end(), std::back_inserter(rvp));

            stackR.push(rvp); 
            stackR.push(lvp);       

            if ( changeDirection ) {
                pCurrent = pCurrent->right;
                changeDirection = false;
            } else {
                pCurrent = pCurrent->left;
            }       
            pNode = &(pCurrent->left);

        } else {
            KdNode **pNodeLeft   = &(pCurrent->left);
            *pNodeLeft  = new KdNode(pCurrent, pv);
            pv = stackR.top();
            stackR.pop();

            KdNode **pNodeRight   = &(pCurrent->right);
            *pNodeRight  = new KdNode(pCurrent,pv);

            pCurrent = pCurrent->parent;
            pNode  = &(pCurrent->right);
            depth--;
            changeDirection = true;
        }           
    }
}


void constructKD(TPointVector &pv) {
    int depth = 0;
    std::sort(pv.begin(), pv.end(), ComparePoints(depth));

    pRoot        = new KdNode(0);
    pRoot->desc  = ( pv.begin() + pv.size()/2)->pt[0];
    pRoot->left  = 0;
    pRoot->right = 0;

    TPointVector lvp, rvp;
    std::copy(pv.begin(), pv.begin() + pv.size()/2, std::back_inserter(lvp));
    std::copy(pv.begin() + pv.size()/2, pv.end(), std::back_inserter(rvp));

    std::stack<TPointVector > stackL, stackR;
    stackL.push(lvp);
    stackR.push(rvp);

    buildLeftTree(stackL);
    buildRightTree(stackR);

}
void readPoints(const char* fileName, TPointVector& points) {
    std::ifstream input(fileName);

    if ( input.peek() != EOF ) {
        while(!input.eof()) {
            int id = 0;
            double x_cord, y_cord;
            input >> id >> x_cord >> y_cord;

            Point t ;
            t.pt[0] = x_cord;
            t.pt[1] = y_cord;
            t.id    = id;

            points.push_back(t);
        }
        input.close();
    }   
}
void _printLevelWise(KdNode *node, std::queue<KdNode *> Q) {
    int depth = 0;
    while ( ! Q.empty()) {
        KdNode *qNode = Q.front();Q.pop();
        if ( qNode->leaf ) {
            std::cout << "[" << qNode->id << "]" << std::setprecision (25) << "(" << qNode->point[0] << "," << qNode->point[1] << ")" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << std::setprecision (25) << qNode->desc << std::endl;
        }       
        if (qNode->left != 0)
            Q.push(qNode->left);
        if (qNode->right != 0)
            Q.push(qNode->right);
    }
}
void PrintLevelWise(KdNode *node) {
    std::queue<KdNode *> Q;
    Q.push(node);
    _printLevelWise(node, Q);
}
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    if ( argc <= 1 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    TPointVector points;
    readPoints(argv[1], points);
    for ( TPointVector::iterator itr = points.begin(); itr != points.end(); ++itr) {
        std::cout << "(" << itr->pt[0] << "," << itr->pt[1] << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    if ( points.size() == 0 )
        return 0;
    constructKD(points);
    PrintLevelWise(pRoot);
    std::cout << "Construction of KD Tree Done " << std::endl;
}
```

Sample Input for which this is failing :

```
1 6 1 
2 5 5 
3 9 6 
4 3 6 
5 4 9
```

Sample Input for which this is working :

```
1 6 1 
2 5 5 
3 9 6 
4 3 6 
5 4 9 
6 4 0 
7 7 9 
8 2 9
```

Comment: How does it "fail" when it is odd? Seg fault?

Comment: Update the question, sorry for not putting the details.

Comment: For interested parties, the "failure" is the omission of one of the nodes read, i.e. only N-1 nodes end up in the tree for N entries (when N is odd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` in `buildLeftTree` and `buildRightTree` does not handle the case where there is an odd number of nodes on the right subtree. In your 5 point example, the `else` case in `buildRightTree` ends up with three points on `stackR`, the first it uses for the `left` node, the second two it silently assigns to the `right` node as if it were the only node.

This is due to your median selection, which uses a different criteria than the one listed on the site you reference.

```
std::size_t median = pv.size() / 2; // degenerates in cases where size() is odd
```

Your selection criteria is supposed to be based on the *median* x or y value and use sublists based on that criteria (which does not assume any given size).

Comment: I will make this change and re-test, But I have another question why there is no iterative KD-Tree implementation available. Is there simple version of KD-tree implementation available( recursive may be fine )

Answer (score 0):

In `else` of `buildLeftTree` and `buildRightTree`.

add

```
if (pv.size() > 1)
{
    pNode = &(pCurrent->right);
    continue;
}
```

between stack's `top` and `pop` function. It'll be OK.

I have another question, when the number of points is million, it'll be very slow to build the tree, how to improve the performance?